# Sci-Fi Book involving Aliens with Halos

Tags: story-identification

I read an old sci-fi book (novel-length, if I remember correctly) in school several years ago. The book was the shelf of an old, British teacher in an international school in northeastern China, if that is relevant. The cover was not super flashy, and I am pretty sure the cover had a blueish-gray background. I would guess it was from the '80s or the '70s, but I can't be sure.

The book started in a large city. The main character was male, and was named Vector. As the story progressed, you learned that characters in the beginning were not human - they were an alien species that originated from another planet, and had golden halos instead of hair. Humans were still on earth, but not in the big city, and they were considered barbarians compared to the aliens. They also had no facial hair. Vector had a good friend (female) named Melody. He learned that all of the females would be sent back to their home planet, since for some reason or another having alien babies was a long and convoluted process.

Vector and Melody decide they love each other and decide to jump ship and escape. The get in big trouble and get chased, but they already left the big city and are out in the wasteland. Apparently Melody's sister Harmony had also done that, with a human man, several years earlier. They are helped by a human officer hired by the aliens, whose name I believe was Node.

The story progresses, and I believe that it ends with the humans overthrowing the aliens, with Vector's mentor Helix being revealed to be a alien-human child, as he grows a golden beard. The aliens leave Earth and Vector and Melody become the king and queen or something like that.

I am very surprised that a Google search based on the names I know has turned up nothing, so I'll leave the Google-fu to you all, since you'll get free Internet points off it anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*King Creature, Come* (US title: *The Creatures*)  by John Rowe Townsend, 1980.
(I used Google's Advanced Book Search)

> In search of a less restrictive way to live, two young people break away from their colony of Persons on the planet Earth, become involved with the inferior Creatures who inhabit Earth, and are thrust into the forefront of a revolution.
>
> <sub>[LibraryThing](https://www.librarything.com/work/1562498/commonknowledge)</sub>

Characters include Vector, Harmony, Helix, Node.

> The Creatures, we soon realize, are Earth folk like ourselves, whereas Persons belong to a superior, cerebral (and, to us, **alien**) race. Safe in their antiseptic outpost, Persons occupy themselves with math, music, and the Dimension Game, while Creature Guards run the Colony and protect it from the filthy, hungry Creatures who overpopulate the city outside its walls. Within the colony is a young girl, **Harmony**, who has picked up from her atypical Person tutor and her own independent nature some very unorthodox fellow feeling for the Creatures. And just as Harmony is about to be **sent back to the home planet for breeding**, she develops some most un-Personlike feelings for fellow student **Vector**, who tells this. At 17, Vector is about due to have the Operation (Persons on Earth do not breed); but he finds that he would rather have Harmony. And so the two sneak out to live among the Creatures, where disease and hunger are still common, hoodlum gangs take over the streets at night, and everyone lives in fear of the Guards, who have come to consider themselves a separate race above the common Creatures.
>
> <sub>[Kirkus Reviews](https://www.kirkusreviews.com/book-reviews/john-rowe-townsend-12/the-creatures/); emphasis added</sub>

Comment: Yup that's it, I'll remember to not just use Google search next time

Comment: I'd have used Google to begin my own search had you not done so already :-)